# DHCPv6 equivalent of `dhcping`?

Tags: networking, dhcp, ipv6

As part of deploying and testing DHCP infrastructure, utilities like `dhcping` which can simulate a DHCP handshake are very handy to have. Unfortunately, `dhcping` is IPv4 (DHCP)-only, with no equivalent tool for IPv6/DHCPv6 in sight. Does anybody know if something like that exists?

I tried using `dhclient -6`'s “no-op” (`-n`) and “one try” (`-1`) modes, but they don't seem to work as advertised. Even when specifying `-n`, `dhclient` removes existing IPv6 addresses from the network interface I'm using for the test. In addition to this, `dhclient` always fails in my environment, even though a `tcpdump` on the same network device shows the DHCPv6 server responding with an advertisement containing the correct (expected) address.

Comment: While the question is interesting, if tcpdump shows the correct handshake and correct answer, the problem is likely a misconfigured dhclient, and I don't see how an IPv6 dhcping (which would be used to debug the handshake) could help with that.

Comment: To clarify: I am not particularly interested in getting `dhclient` to work per se. DHCPv6 works for me, I'm just interested in setting up a monitoring plugin (nagios-style) to make sure it remains that way, i.e. that the server is always responding. For IPv4 we have a monitoring plugin that essentially does the equivalent of calling `dhcping`. It was merely trying to use `dhclient -6` (to replace `dchping`) for DHCPv6 monitoring that failed.

Comment: Please edit the question with this additional information; the comments are not guaranteed to stay.